# How to read local (Client) file with GWT?

Tags: javascript, file, html, gwt

I would like to use GWT to read and parse local csv file. 
EDIT: Local file here means client file.

I know I can use HTML5 with javascript to achieve that, but I would like to use GWT to do it.

One way of doing it is by using JavaScript Native Interface (JSNI), however I think it beats the purpose of using GWT.

Another way of doing this would be upload the file to server, and send it back as a json. But I feel it's not the best way of doing it.

Please advise. Thanks.

EDIT: I intend to design a desktop app, so I try to avoid using any web-server scripting.

Answer (score 7):

Using jsni doesn't beat the purpose of gwt, sometimes you need to use it as a wrapper to functionality not yet available in gwt or an external javascript library. Instead of writting jsni access to the file api you can use one of several third party libraries available that implement html5 file access, like http://code.google.com/p/lib-gwt-file

Answer (score -1):

A quick search returned this SO question: [Read text file in google GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708306/read-text-file-in-google-gwt)

Although GWT doesn't support `java.io.InputStream`, it looks like you could make a request to your CSV File and then parse it.

Remember that if you will host on AppEngine, [you won't have a filesystem available](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html) so you'll have to have the files hosted elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked this link out before. My impression was it's sending the file to server. However I will have a second read here.

Comment: Gwt is compiled to javascript and so no access on the client to java.io is available because it' not available in javascript, even while you might have access to it in development mode. so this suggestion makes no sense.

Comment: There are jre emulation libraries though... http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/RefJreEmulation.html although I'm not suggesting he use java.io so your down vote is completely unmerited.