# How can I display the contents of a textfile on a Flextable in GWT?

Tags: gwt

How can I display the contents of a textfile (a Notepad) on a `Flextable` in GWT? I have been trying to use `FileInputStream` but I get an error that

> Plugin failed to Connect at Development mode Server at 127.0.0.9997.

I have tried clearing the cache but it didn't help? Does GWT actually allow reading from a textfile? And how can we print the contents apart from on a `FlexTable`.

Comment: Read text file in google GWT? - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2708980/432903

Comment: You need to read the file server side and then pass the data to the client side. The easiest way would be to do a file upload.

Comment: GWT doesn't emulate all the JRE, just one part (https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation). FileInputStream is one of those things that cannot be translated to JavaScript. That's why you should upload the file, read it on server and then send someway the data to the client to show the content.

Comment: The reason GWT doesn't complain until runtime is because in DevMode is not trying to compile to JavaScript. Even some non-translated classes could be used in DevMode but GWT compilation will throw an error later. So GWT compilation has the last word on this isssues.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot actually read file in GWT(client side). One option would be allow the user to upload the file, and in the server side you read the file and send the contents to client. 
In the client you can use the desired widget to show the content.