# Dynamic Properties in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, properties, internationalization, gxt

Is there a way to load data at run time from a *.properties* file?

Using the `Constants` interface the data is hardcoded and I need to recompile for update my properties. I want to do this without recompile.

I read about the class `Dictionary`, but my data will be shown in the HTML host page. Is it secure?

Is there another way?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708306/read-text-file-in-google-gwt. You can store your property file on server side and get its content with `RequestBuilder`. Also you can process it on server side and put it into `JSON` format in property-value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a RequestBuilder to fetch .js file with i18n string key/value pair and then parse it using GWT Dictionary class.

GWT I18n Guide - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n

Using GWT Dictionary - http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html

Note -

1) We use it for processing only label values which require I18N.

2) We use it with htpps, XSS and XSRF features enabled in GWT.