# Reading the contents of a text file

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-highcharts

I'm writing an application for displaying chrats. I'm using GWT Highcharts (by Moxie Group) to display the results. I add a random number to the chart and it works without a problem.

But I want to load numbers from a text file. I just want to read the contents of a file and put it on the array or something similar. How can I do this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a small program as like the below to achieve that:

You may have to change the logic to read elements the way you want it for your GWT highcharts!

```
public class ReadATextFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (RandomAccessFile readFile = new RandomAccessFile("C:\\Test.txt", "r");) {
            int EOF = (int) readFile.length();
            System.out.println("Length of the file is (" + EOF + ") bytes");
            //Considering to read the first 150 bytes out of 168 bytes on the file
            readFile.seek(0);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[EOF];

            readFile.readFully(bytes);
            readFile.close();

            System.out.println(new String(bytes));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Where the Test.txt file's contents is something like this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11
```

Comment: Or you could use a solution as like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708306/read-text-file-in-google-gwt?rq=1)

Comment: Your shown code will only work on the serverside of an GWT application. Therefore only files which can be read directly by the server can be accessed. If users should provide files, you need to implement a file upload. Then the server can process the uploaded file.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer @Akkusativobjekt, I realized that hence added a comment showing how that can be achieved via the link shared